# Auth0 LoginAsync() Authentication window not passing values back to app

Tags: vb.net, auth0

I have a simple vb App where on form load Auth0 login event is triggered.

```
Private Async Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 Dim loginresult = Await client.LoginAsync()

        idtoken = LoginResult.IdentityToken

    End Sub
```

A Auth0 popup window appears where the user enters credentials. On successful authentication the window is supposed to close and pass on the access tokens to my app.

this works flawlessly on testing. But when the app is published the authentication window does not close nor does pass any values to my app.
[the window appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZrlV.png)

please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Sameer. Are you closing the popup within your allowed callback URLs with the production route? Are you using Lock? If pop ups are blocked in the browser of users you run the risk of the Popup not functioning as intended. Is there a reason why you decided to not leverage the [Universal Login Experience](https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login)?

Comment: Good Afternoon, Sorry for the delay in getting back on this.

As i'm using vb, i'm using [Auth0 WPF / Winforms SDK Quickstarts: Login](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/wpf-winforms/01-login).

I'm not doing anything addition to the above code to log in and capturing the id token

Comment: Also upon more testing I found out that this is happening only on machines older than Windows 10. On other Windows 10 machines the code works like a charm.

to take care of that i also added DWORD for the app to emulate IE 11. Still it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this exact issue by building a new WebBrowserBrowser object and passing it to Auth0Client constructor using the Auth0ClientOptions.

```
        var options = new Auth0ClientOptions
        {
            Domain = "******.us.auth0.com",
            ClientId = "*************",
            Browser = new WebBrowserBrowser("You Application Login", 500, 760),
        };
        _client = new Auth0Client(options);
```